# Determinant $\left|\begin{smallmatrix} y+z &x &y \\ z+x &z &x \\ x+y &y &z \\ \end{smallmatrix}\right|= (x+y+z)(z-x)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Tomorrow I have to attend a math exam.
So I have to prove a problem on determinant.
The Problem:
$$\left|\begin{matrix}
 y+z &x &y \cr
z+x &z &x \cr
x+y &y &z \cr
\end{matrix}\right|=(x+y+z)(x-z)^2$$

This is I have to prove.

Condition: No direct Expanding, Only Properties,no Factor Method should be used.

I tried many methods I can't able to prove it. Please someone Help to solve this.

Comment: "I tried many methods": Show them to us, then we can improve your attempts.

Comment: First, use linearity.

Comment: **Hint:** try some column operations

Comment: I used this


$$\left|\begin{matrix}
 y &x &y \cr
z&z &x \cr
x &y &z \cr
\end{matrix}\right|+\left|\begin{matrix}
  z &x &y \cr
   x &z &x \cr
   y &y &z \cr \end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}
  z+y &x &y \cr
   x+z &z &x \cr
   y+x &y &z \cr \end{matrix}\right|$$

Comment: @Henry W. Not allowed, see original post.

Comment: What's meant by *no Factor Method* but with the answer in factor form?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using row operations. Since you want to have $x+y+z$ in the result, adding all rows together as the first step practically suggests itself.
$\begin{vmatrix}
 y+z &x &y \\
 z+x &z &x \\
 x+y &y &z \\
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
 y+z &x &y \\
 z+x &z &x \\
2(x+y+z)&x+y+z&x+y+z\\
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)\begin{vmatrix}
 y+z &x &y \\
 z+x &z &x \\
  2  &1 &1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)\begin{vmatrix}
 y+z &x &y \\
 z-x &z-x&0 \\
  2  &1 &1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)(z-x)\begin{vmatrix}
 y+z &x &y \\
  1  &1 &0 \\
  2  &1 &1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)(z-x)\begin{vmatrix}
 z-y &x-y&0 \\
  1  &1 &0 \\
  2  &1 &1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)(z-x)\begin{vmatrix}
 z-x &0 &0 \\
  1  &1 &0 \\
  2  &1 &1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+y+z)(z-x)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the "Factor Method" is. Maybe it's this, but here is an approach all the same.

The determinant is going to be a homogeneous cubic polynomial in $x,y,z$ since each entry is homogeneous linear.

Adding the three rows, it's clear that if $x+y+z=0$, then the determinant would be $0$ because it would make the three rows sum to a zero row. So $(x+y+z)$ is a factor of the determinant.

The determinant is $0$ if $x=z$ since the first column would then be the sum of the second and third columns. So $(x-z)$ is a factor.

Thus far the determinant is $$(x+y+z)(x-z)(ax+by+cz)$$

The coefficient of $x^3$ must be $1$ because there is only one product that produces $x^3$ (the $(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)$ product, which is $1x^3$). A similar observation can be made for $z$. From these observations, you can conclude $a=1$ and $c=-1$. Considering $y$ though, the coefficient of $y^3$ is $0$ since $y$ is missing from the middle row. And also the coefficient of $y^2$ is $0$, once you consider the three products that contribute to the coefficient of $y^2$. [The $(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)$ product gives $y^2$ a coefficient of $-x$; the $(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)$ product gives it a coefficient of $-z$; the $(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)$ gives it a coefficient of $(x+z)$.] So $b=0$, and the determinant is $$(x+y+z)(x-z)(x-z)$$